# Requests.get Json format. strange ouput to me

Tags: python, google-sheets, python-requests

I'm a beginner in python or any other programming language. I'm trying to learn python to request API's data in Json format and then export to google-sheet to work together with my financials data. But my first step is to fix this output error:

```
import requests

def crypto_price():
    response = requests.get('https://api.gdax.com/products/ETH-USD/ticker')
    r_json = response.json()
    return float(r_json[1]['price'])
print(crypto_price)
```

is outputing something like this:

```
<function crypto_price at 0x7fc257d601e0>
```

instead of like that:

```
{"trade_id":55904930,
"price":"117.26",
"size":"0.05016553",
"time":"2020-03-18T01:43:49.023244Z",
"bid":"117.23",
"ask":"117.26",
"volume":"353473.96787048"}
```

this is strange to me because it is only happening when I use "def".

Comment: You have to call the function. Add `()`!

Comment: Can I ask you about the relationship between your question and the tag of `google-apps-script`?

Comment: @Tenaike, saying again, i'm going to export to google sheets.I'll try to do some scripts

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your goal from your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the function object, so you'll get an output with the function's pointer at runtime.

replace

```
print(crypto_price)
```

with

```
print(crypto_price())
```